# How to get the same color cells from the grid in image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, grid

I have the following image :

[image]

I want to extract the cells of the grid with same color and save the coordinates of the same color. Like all the orange cell coordinates which are (19,0),(18,0),(17,0),(19,1) and so on, assume that indexing is starting from (0,0). Further, I will use that cell as the patch of the image. How can I do this? Will it require me to do some sort of masking? I am completely new to image processing. Can someone guide me ?

Comment: May by resize this image to size  20x20 pixels and posterize it...

Comment: @AlexAlex : it will not solve my purpose! I need to first idetify the grid , cut them into patches where each patch is a grid cell and seggregate the same color patch which is my task at hand